# Trying to get the year out of a date with sed

Tags: sed, substitution

I'm using the following command to get the year out of a string using sed.

```
echo 1234-1-12 | sed -r 's/(\d{4})-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}/\1/'
```

but somehow it returns the entire date instead of the year.

getting `1234-1-12`

expecting `1234`

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `date` command:

```
string="1234-1-12"
date -d "${string}" +%Y
```

Output:

```
1234
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple ***grep*** approach:

```
echo "1234-1-12" | grep -o '^[^-]*'
```

The output:

```
1234
```